# Changing CSS based on button state

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, html

in my application i post data to the server via ajax, while data is being posted to the server i want to be able to show the user that something is indeed happening, now a simple way to do this will be to display a loading gif.  What i actually want to do is change the state of the button that was clicked.  I have 4 classes in my css:

1. btn-ready-state
2. btn-working-state
3. btn-completed-state
4. btn-failed-state

Now each button has a class of **btn-ready-state** when you click the button the class changes to **btn-working-state** where the text of the button changes to "working" and a small loading icon appears inside the button. When the operation is done successfully it switches to **btn-completed-state** if it fails then **btn-failed-state**.  Now i have been able to do this in my code with jquery but the code is so messy and untidy and doesn't work properly with angular.  I have been told i can use directives to achieve this but since i am new to angular i am confused as to how to implement this with directives, i do know what a directive is and how to make one, my issue here is the implementation of this particular feature. This is how i did it with jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var $loading = $('#loading');

            $loading.on("change", function(){ //bind() for older jquery version
                var index = parseInt($('#loading').val());
                var done = parseInt($('#done').val());

                if (done === 0) {
                    $('.btn.ticket:eq(' + [index] + ')').removeClass('btn-ready-state');
                    $('.btn.ticket:eq(' + [index] + ')').addClass('btn-working-state');

                    $('.btn.ticket:eq(' + [index] + ')').find('.text').text('Working..');

                    $('.btn.ticket:eq(' + [index] + ')').find('.state').addClass('loading');
                    $('.btn.ticket:eq(' + [index] + ')').find('i').replaceWith('<img src="/images/loading.gif">' + '</img>');
                } else {
                    $('.btn.ticket:eq(' + [index] + ')').removeClass('btn-ready-state');
                    $('.btn.ticket:eq(' + [index] + ')').removeClass('btn-working-state');
                    $('.btn.ticket:eq(' + [index] + ')').addClass('btn-completed-state');

                    $('.btn.ticket:eq(' + [index] + ')').find('.text').text('Added');

                    $('.btn.ticket:eq(' + [index] + ')').find('.state').addClass('done');
                    $('.btn.ticket:eq(' + [index] + ')').find('i').replaceWith('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok state"></i>');
                    $('.btn.ticket:eq(' + [index] + ')').find('img').replaceWith('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok state"></i>');
                }


            }).change(); //could be change() or trigger('change')

        });

        $(document).on("click", ".btn.ticket", function() {
            var index = $(".btn.ticket").index(this);
            $('#loading').val(index).change();
        });

        $(document).on("click", ".btn.next", function() {
            $(this).removeClass('btn-ready-state');
            $(this).addClass('btn-working-state');

            $(this).find('.text').text('Working..');

            $(this).find('.state').addClass('loading');
            $(this).find('i').replaceWith('<img src="/images/loading.gif">' + '</img>');
        });
</script>
```

This is a sample html of the button:

```
<button class="btn-ready-state"><span class="img"></span><span class="text"></span></button>
```

Comment: would normally do most of this using `ng-class`

Comment: Yeah but i also change the text and img of the button as well.  Edited my post.

Comment: Very simple to do using angular expressions. I would suggest you not use jQuery at all while learning angular

Comment: Please show me how, an example would be really helpful since i am quite new to angular.

Comment: `<a class="btn next" ng-class="{'btn-ready-state': isReady, 'btn-working-state': isWorking}"><img ng-src="{{imageUrl}}" /></span><span class="text">{{text}}</span>` there is no rule saying you cannot use multiple directives on the same element and inside it.

Comment: Wow thanks that's seems simple enough, let me try it out. :)

Comment: @pixelbits why is it not angularjs? Please read the whole question and don't skip bits of it.

Answer (score 0):

90% of the script changes the style. You said you like to indicate ajax? Look at this:

```
<script>
    jQuery.ajaxSetup({
      ajaxStart:function(){
        jQuery('body').toggleClass('ajaxing', true);
      },
      ajaxStop:function(){
        jQuery('body').toggleClass('ajaxing', false);
      }
    })
</script>
```

This is better because you dont need to repeat yourself (DRY-Principle).

So instead of doing this in javascript:

```
$(this).find('i').replaceWith('<img src="/images/loading.gif">' + '</img>');
```

You can now do all the graphical stuff you did in javascript in CSS:

```
.ajaxing i {
  background-image: url(/images/loading.gif);
}
// for text you can use this:
.ajaxing .btn.ticket:active:before{
  position:relative;
  content:'Working...';
}
```

Or in anguarjs:

```
angular.module('app', []).value('loadManager', {
  c: 0,
  requested: function() { c++; document.body.class="ajaxing";},
  responded: function() { c--; if(!c)document.body.class="";}
}).factory('loadingInterceptor', function(loadManager) {
  return {
    request: function(e) {
      loadManager.requested();
          return e;
        },
    response: function(e) {
      loadManager.responded();
      return e;
    },
  }
});
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('loadManager');
```

All of this is only an example. I do not know the complete HTML you are using.

Comment: Thanks but this solution is in jquery i would like to move away from jquery, how would i implement this in angularjs? To be specific i mean the ajaxSetup bit since this is actually my first time seeing it.

Comment: You know jquery a little bit but move to angularjs what you compleatly dont know?